# How to get R Igraph values for a weighted PageRank to match Gephi

Tags: r, igraph, gephi, pagerank

I am working on getting my PageRank values from igraph in R to match those I get from Gephi.  I have followed this example: https://www.briggsby.com/personalized-pagerank
and my igraph values match the weighted values this example has. But Gephi produces a different value for weighted PageRank and I'm unsure why.  When I run this as an unweighted PageRank, I get the same results between igraph and Gephi.

The network I'm importing is simple to get the math correct -

| Source | Target | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1.0 |
| B | C | 1.0 |
| C | B | 1.0 |
| C | A | 0.5 |
| A | C | 1.0 |
| C | D | 0.1 |
| D | A | 0.5 |

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
library(igraph);
library(plyr);
set.seed(123);
mydf <- data.frame(from=TestPageRank$Source, to=TestPageRank$Target);
mygraph <- graph.data.frame(mydf, directed = T);
c<-data.frame(users=V(mygraph)$name, page_rank = page_rank(mygraph, directed = T, damping = 0.85, weights = TestPageRank$Weight)$vector, degree=degree(mygraph));
```

The PageRanks I'm returning are as follows:

| Node | igraph Weighted PageRank | Gephi Weighted PageRank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.1960 | 0.2373 |
| B | 0.3373 | 0.2761 |
| C | 0.4075 | 0.3732 |
| D | 0.0591 | 0.1133 |

In this example, the ranking is at least the same, but when I apply this to my larger networks with thousands of nodes, the node ranking by PageRank is very different.  Any thoughts on why this might be? Or how I can modify my R code to match the Gephi PageRank values?

Here's the updated code with import:

```
df <- structure(list(Source = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "C", "D"), 
                     Target = c("B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "D", "A"), 
                     Weight = c(1,1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.1, 0.5)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
page_rank(g, weights = E(g)$Weight, directed = T, damping = 0.85)$vector
degree(g)
```

And the output from the above:

```
         A          B          C          D 
0.19602465 0.33730560 0.40752024 0.05914951
```

Comment: Please provide the data in a copyable format.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your results with igraph. Please provide a minimal reproducible example, with copyable code. You will find guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Here is your datafile as copyable CSV:

```
Source,Target,Weight
A,B,1.
B,C,1.
C,B,1.
C,A,0.5
A,C,1.
C,D,0.1
D,B,0.5
```

We get this after using `read.csv`:

```
df <- structure(list(Source = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "C", "D"), 
    Target = c("B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B"), Weight = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.1, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
page_rank(g, weights = E(g)$Weight)
```

```
$vector
         A          B          C          D 
0.14857410 0.37354978 0.41816130 0.05971482
```

Using the ARPACK method, which is an entirely distinct algorithm, we get the same:

```
> page_rank(g, weights = E(g)$Weight, algo = 'arpack')
$vector
         A          B          C          D 
0.14857410 0.37354978 0.41816130 0.05971482
```

These numbers differ from what you quote, but I cannot tell why without a reproducible example.

I should note that I worked on igraph's PageRank code and I believe that it is exceedingly unlikely that it would give incorrect results.

Comment: My apologies, it's not reproducible because I had a typo in the data. The last row should be d-a not d-b. I've updated it and added the code. I believe igraph to be the correct version since it is matching to what I get with Python. I had been using Gephi to "validate" my findings but now I'm thinking the Gephi algorithm is incorrect.

Comment: @MAb2021 Python does not have built in features to calculate PageRank. Which specific Python library are you talking about?

Comment: I used networkx and followed the example in the link in my post. It matches what I get from igraph. But the two do not match Gephi.

Comment: @MAb2021 I am not deeply familiar with Gephi, but typical reasons for differences in PageRank results are: 1. not using the same damping factor 2. not using the same directedness 3. different interpretations of how to proceed when the walker gets stuck — does not apply here as you have no sink nodes 4. different handling of multi-edges or self-loops — does not apply here as you don't have these

Comment: these are all the reasons I went with this simplistic example dataset. My actual network has 2-3k nodes and many of the other factors you specified. But for validation, this set has no loops and no dangling nodes. Gephi allows the user to specify damping factor (which I set to 0.85) and directedness which is set to true. I have been using gephi as my “gold standard” until now but I think I will need to change my approach.

Comment: @MAb2021 I just tried with Gephi, and I got the same results as with igraph.